# Are there common/trivial/archaic names for any of the periods of the periodic table?

Tags: nomenclature, periodic-table, history-of-chemistry

There are "common names" for all of the s and p block groups of elements (alkali metals, alkaline earth metals, icosagens, crystallogens, pnicto­gens, chal­co­gens, halo­gens, noble gases) (although some of those aren't that common), "Trivial names" for some of those aswell (triels, tetrels, pentels), and up to d-block referring to a group as "the litest element in said group" group/family is accepted nomenclature.
What my question is is has there ever been a name used in any reasonable capacity or even proposed for any periods of the table beyond just period #? ie. is there any name I can use for the set of elements containing just H and He.
Period 6 and 7 f-block elements have commonly used names and this is kinda what I am looking for but not quite.

Comment: What would be the point in that? Also if you know triels, tetrels, or even some icosagens, I've likely never heard about, then I doubt we got much to add.

Answer (score 7):

Though I don't know of terms for each row, there are a few that describe a horizontal section of the periodic table.

1. Astronomers refer to anything other than H and He (first period) as [metals](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/research/topic/elemental-abundances), so in that usage, the first period would be "nonmetals"... This hardly a useful *chemistry* definition, though ;-)
2. [Lanthanides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanide) and [Actinides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinide) are sections of a period, but certainly not the whole row.
3. [Scandides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-block_contraction) are used for *some* period-4 elements, though again not a whole row. (courtesy Oscar Lanzi)
4. [Transuranic element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transuranium_element) is a horizontal set, but also not a single period. The concept is more useful in nuclear physics rather than chemistry.
5. [Heavy metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_metals) is far too broad a term, also, and omits nonmetals and alkalis (other than Ra). <sub>[BTW, I propose Malmsteenium for the next heavy metal to be created.]</sub>

Comment: From the pattern established by Lanthanides,  Actinides, and Scandides, for my purposes I am just gonna go with calling each period block combination by the first element in that set with the ending changed to -ides

Comment: Alkali-metal "-ides" would also be compounds containing anions of these metals.

Comment: The first extra row on the bottom of the table is known as rare earths.

Comment: Also: [Coinage Metals](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_General_Chemistry_(Petrucci_et_al.)/23%3A_The_Transition_Elements/23.6%3A_Group_11%3A_Copper_Silver_and_Gold)

Comment: Coinage metals are not a horizontal *period*, but rather a *group* or *column* with similar properties, e.g., Cu, Ag, Au. The question was for, "a name used in any reasonable capacity or even proposed for any **periods** of the table."

Answer (score 3):

The word "scandides" is sometimes used for the Period 4 transition elements from scandium (the namesake) through zinc, particularly in the label "scandide contraction" for what is more commonly called the [d-block contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-block_contraction). As with the lanthanides and actinides, the label does not cover the period as a whole.